# Add new list row based on drop down selection

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying the following.

I have the function that displays a hidden list based on the dropdown selecttion.

Please visit here to see it:

http://jsfiddle.net/vSyK6/28/

What I am trying to do is when Option1 is selected, it will display the content of #List-Option1 Content and if Option2 is selected it will display content #List-Option2.

Now, what I want to accomplish is when both content is displayed and if you select again of the options it should add another list with the option selected.

Basically if we go by this order:

Option1....then
Option2....then

We select again Option1 and it should display like this

Option1 Content
Option2 Content
Option1 Content

if we select Option2 again it should display like this:

Option1 Content
Option2 Content
Option1 Content
Option2 Content

Right now what it does it displays the selected item in the last row of the list. It doesn't add a new list row. This function of course is not implemented. I need the solution for that :-)

Hope i make sense :)

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest the following:

```
$('#List-Option1, #List-Option2').hide();

$('#category').change(function() {
    var str = $('#category').val();
    $('#List-' + str).clone(true, true).attr('id', function(i,v){
        return v.replace(/\d+/,'') + (parseInt($('#box li[id^="List-Option"]').length,10) + 1);
    }).appendTo('#box ul').show();
});​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/vSyK6/31/).

References:

- [`attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/).
- [attribute-starts-with (`attribute^="value"]`) selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/).
- [`clone()`](http://api.jquery.com/clone/).
- [`parseInt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt).
- [`string.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace).

Comment: hi David, thanks for your help. Your solutions works as well however my majore goal is to call a function that makes some calculations. I used your code and the calculation script in there. See here.....http://jsfiddle.net/vSyK6/37/    The way it should work is when you enter an amount in the empty textbox, which is the Content of Option2, it should call the calculation function. But when you select the again the second option and it should call the function where we calculate again but separate from the first empty textbox....Hope this is clear :-)

Comment: Basically, when we have two empty textboxes displayed, it should call the same function but calculate it separately....

Comment: Then you need to ask a question that specifies that, don't ask a question and then add a requirement once it's been answered. I'm sorry, but it is somewhat discourteous and unfair. But please: ask another question, with the specific requirements, and I'll take a look and see if I can help you out with it. =)

Comment: Yes...you're right...i apologize...i will add a new posting for this. Thanks David and Sushi...I appreciate your help :)

Comment: I made a new post on this...thank you.....http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12877232/call-same-function-by-a-cloned-list-row

Answer (score 1):

Updated [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vSyK6/29/). I am using jQuery clone to create new option content . Note do not use id if you want to repeat same code multiple time.

Comment: great. Almost there. I am also trying to call another function but its not working. The other function that I have is when you enter a text in textbox #Input2 it should pop out an alert box. Please view here: http://jsfiddle.net/vSyK6/32/      Any idea why its not calling that function ?

Comment: working jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/vSyK6/33/. As I already suggested don't use id for multiple element.  Event will not fire to those elements which are not present at time of event binding.